# For each element in list add class from value in related element and pass it on

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown that gets values from a dynamic html table and adds them to the dropdown:

```
function options (){
  document.querySelectorAll(".accname").forEach(element => {
    let dropdown = document.querySelector("#myDropdown");
    let options = document.querySelectorAll("#myDropdown > a").length;
    dropdown.innerHTML = dropdown.innerHTML + '<a id="accselect' + (options + 1) + '" onclick="selectAccount(\'' + element.innerText + '\')"> ' + element.innerText + ' </a>'
  });

function selectAccount (value) {
  input2 = document.getElementById("new_account");
  input2.value = value;
}
```

Each .accname has a sibling element with a child that contains the account currency. I'm trying to make it so that when an element from the dropdown is clicked I can change the currency symbol on the next input field. But I cant figure out how to get this information.

The html table containing the info I want is made up of rows that follow this format:

```
    <tr id="acc_row1acc_table1">
      <td id="acc_name1" class="accname">Cash</td>
      <td id="acc_balance1" class="accbal">$5322.54</td>
      <td class="edtbutton"><a class="account_currency">USD</a></td></tr>
```

I tried adding the following Jquery to the function:

```
let getacc_curr = $('.accname').next('td.edtbutton').find('.account_currency').text();
```

But it just gets all elements... How can I get the value (and keep it hidden) but pass it on when an element in the dropdown is clicked?

I tried making a separate "for each" function to assign a number value to each currency corresponding to the list length in the dropdown, or to add the value to each dropdown item as a class, but I have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: Do the id's of the rows increment `acc_row1acc_table1, acc_row1acc_table2` etc?

Comment: Create a working fiddle using `<>` button in editor and you will get much higher chances of  answers. None of your questions have [mre].  You are already using the code in question from my snippet I answered before, why not just copy it here and adjust it? You are talking about clicking on drop down people do not see...

Comment: @charlietfl yes there a three tables in total

Comment: @iKiK Here's a min rep example: https://codepen.io/schinken82/pen/bGebOPr the currency for all accounts in this example are USD but they could also be EUR, GBP, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this but I would suggest next:

While creating the drop-down also save currency in data attribute of drop down option:

**1.get currency:**

```
let currency = element.parentElement.querySelector(".edtbutton > .account_currency").innerText;
```

**2. add it in** `data-curency`; `data-curency="' + currency + '"`

```
dropdown.innerHTML = dropdown.innerHTML + '<a data-curency="' + currency + '" id="accselect' + (options + 1) + '" onclick="selectAccount(\'' + element.innerText + '\')"> ' + element.innerText + ' </a>';
```

now you can acces that data with: `.getAttribute("data-curency")`

I added new event listener while making the drop down for each option:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('#myDropdown > a').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    document.querySelector("#new_amount").value = event.target.getAttribute("data-curency")
  })
})
```

example here is getting the data of clciked option with:`event.target.getAttribute("data-curency")`

I append it in  `#new_amount` input, but you can do what ever you want with it, it was unclear what you actually want to do with it.

**Working example:**

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function dropdownFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.add("show");
  document.getElementById('myDropdown').innerHTML = '';
}
//Searchable dropdown
function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("new_account");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
//Get the dropdown content
function options() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".accname").forEach(element => {
    let dropdown = document.querySelector("#myDropdown");
    let options = document.querySelectorAll("#myDropdown > a").length;
    let currency = element.parentElement.querySelector(".edtbutton > .account_currency").innerText;
    dropdown.innerHTML = dropdown.innerHTML + '<a data-curency="' + currency + '" id="accselect' + (options + 1) + '" onclick="selectAccount(\'' + element.innerText + '\')"> ' + element.innerText + ' </a>';
    document.querySelectorAll('#myDropdown > a').forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener('click', event => {
        document.querySelector("#new_amount").nextElementSibling.innerText = event.target.getAttribute("data-curency")
      })
    })

  });
}
//if dropdown is visible, on off click hide
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbutton')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
//Fill selected account as input
function selectAccount(value) {
  input = document.getElementById("new_account");
  input.value = value;
}
```

```css
/* Account selection drop-down */


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="dropbutton" placeholder="Account" id="new_account" onclick="dropdownFunction(); options()" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
</div>


<input type="text" id="new_amount" placeholder="Amount">
<a class="currencysymbol">$</a>

<br><br><br>Table with data<br>



<div class="Accounts">
  <br><br><button type="button" class="collapsible"><h3 id="Accounts">&nbsp;Fiat Accounts</h3></button>
  <div class="content" id="acc_list">
    <table class="acc_table" id="acc_table1">
      <tr id=acc_row1acc_table1>
        <td id="acc_name1" class="accname">Cash</td>
        <td id="acc_balance1" class="accbal">$5322.54</td>
        <td class=edtbutton><a class="account_currency">USD</a><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id=acc_row2acc_table1>
        <td id="acc_name2" class="accname">Credit Card</td>
        <td id=acc_balance2 class="accbal">$1362.21</td>
        <td class=edtbutton><a class="account_currency">USD</a><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id=acc_row3acc_table1>
        <td id="acc_name3" class="accname">Checking Account</td>
        <td id=acc_balance3 class="accbal">$4322.50</td>
        <td class=edtbutton><a class="account_currency">USD</a><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id=acc_row4acc_table1>
        <td id="acc_name4" class="accname">Savings Account</td>
        <td id=acc_balance4 class="accbal">$12322.50</td>
        <td class=edtbutton><a class="account_currency">USD</a><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
      <h4 id="acc">&nbsp<button data-modal-target="#modal" class="add_account" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayadd(); accounttablenum('acc_table1')">+</button></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Stocks & Commodeties">
    <br><button type="button" class="collapsible"><h3>&nbsp;Stocks & Commodeties</h3></button>
    <div class="content" id="acc_list">
      <table class="acc_table" id="acc_table2">
        <tr id=acc_row1acc_table2>
          <td id="acc_name1" class="accname">DOW JONES 50 TITANS</td>
          <td id="acc_balance1" class="accbal">$5322.54</td>
          <td class=edtbutton><a class="account_currency">USD</a><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id=acc_row2acc_table2>
          <td id="acc_name2" class="accname">Oil Certificates</td>
          <td id=acc_balance2 class="accbal">$1362.21</td>
          <td class=edtbutton><a class="account_currency">USD</a><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id=acc_row3acc_table2>
          <td id="acc_name3" class="accname">AAPL</td>
          <td id=acc_balance3 class="accbal">$4322.50</td>
          <td class=edtbutton><a class="account_currency">USD</a><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id=acc_row4acc_table2>
          <td id="acc_name4" class="accname">Physical Gold</td>
          <td id=acc_balance4 class="accbal">$12322.50</td>
          <td class=edtbutton><a class="account_currency">USD</a><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div>
        <h4 id="acc">&nbsp<button data-modal-target="#modal" class="add_account" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayadd(); accounttablenum('acc_table2')">+</button></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Digital Currencies">
    <br><button type="button" class="collapsible"><h3>&nbsp;Digital Currencies</h3></button>
    <div class="content" id="acc_list">
      <table class="acc_table" id="acc_table3">
        <tr id=acc_row1acc_table3>
          <td id="acc_name1" class="accname">Bitcoin</td>
          <td id="acc_balance1" class="accbal">$5322.54</td>
          <td class=edtbutton><a class="account_currency">USD</a><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id=acc_row2acc_table3>
          <td id="acc_name2" class="accname">Ethereum</td>
          <td id=acc_balance2 class="accbal">$1362.21</td>
          <td class=edtbutton><a class="account_currency">USD</a><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id=acc_row3acc_table3>
          <td id="acc_name3" class="accname">Chainlink</td>
          <td id=acc_balance3 class="accbal">$4322.50</td>
          <td class=edtbutton><a class="account_currency">USD</a><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id=acc_row4acc_table3>
          <td id="acc_name4" class="accname">DAI</td>
          <td id=acc_balance4 class="accbal">$12322.50</td>
          <td class=edtbutton><a class="account_currency">USD</a><button class="edit_account" data-modal-target="#modal" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayedit()">✎</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div>
        <h4 id="acc">&nbsp<button data-modal-target="#modal" class="add_account" id="editaccounts" onclick="sayadd(); accounttablenum('acc_table3')">+</button></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And please make minimal reproducible example next time when asking question like i mentioned in comment, or at list link it with code-pen. I believe a lot of your questions stays un-answered because people do not see relevant example codes and snippet.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I'll be sure to include working examples in the future. One thing, after the amount input field I have `<a class="currencysymbol">$</a>` That is what want changed. I tried replacing querySelector("#new_amount") with (".currencysymbol") so it updates this element instead but I couldn't get it working. Am I missing something?

Comment: @smurf41 No problem, and yet again you don't have filed with `.currencysymbol` in nether code-pen or your question. If you say its after amount and is sibling, you can just simply add  `.nextElementSibling.innerText` and need to use `innerText` to change text of `a` element: `document.querySelector("#new_amount").nextElementSibling.innerText =`. Just one way to do it. I updated the fiddle. Btw, you need to gioogle and will eventualy memorize what fields can be changed with what code, `value` is for input and few more elements, you have `innerText` and so on for the rest. Always search for it.